# Why is the Advanced section Update tab in Thunderbird blank?

Tags: gnome, 15.04, configuration, thunderbird, settings

I recently install Thunderbird, but found that in the Preferences, if you go to the `Advanced` section, and then the `Update` tab, you find that it is blank:

[image]

Is this a bug? Or is it meant to be so on my system for some reason?

---

**OS Information:**

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
Flavour: GNOME
GNOME Version: 3.16

**Package Information:**

```
thunderbird:
  Installed: 1:31.8.0+build1-0ubuntu0.15.04.1
  Candidate: 1:31.8.0+build1-0ubuntu0.15.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 1:31.8.0+build1-0ubuntu0.15.04.1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:31.6.0+build1-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same here and it's not a bug. It's the normal behavior, if you installed Thunderbird via package manager (`apt`).

In this tab you configure whether Thunderbird automatically checks for updates. Since the package manager (`apt`) takes care of updates, this tab is empty.

And it makes no sense to use this tab, as Thunderbird doesn't runs with `sudo` rights and therefore can't update.

Comment: Well the "bug" could be that it should (in my opinion) show a message there to avoid confusion. Something like "Updates are provided by your package manager".

Comment: @Rinzwind No, that's a feature request ;)

Comment: And feature requests are bugs ;-)